# Merge contents of multiple svg files

Tags: scripting, svg

I have 3 svg files that I would like to combine into a single svg file.  Each file has a single path tag in it and I would like to put the path tag from each svg file into one file.  I figure there is probably a way to do this with a script.  At least I hope there is, I have a several hundred of the groups of 3 files.

Comment: Since SVG is XML, probably a xmlstarlet invocation away.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with, not sure if it is the most optimal way to do this but it seems to work with the few test I have done.  Just need to modify this to run on all the files in a directory.

```
$file_1 = '1a.svg'
$file_1_con = Get-Content -raw -Path $file_1

$file_2 = '1b.svg'
$file_2_con = Get-Content -raw -Path $file_2

$file_3 = '1c.svg'
$file_3_con = Get-Content -raw -Path $file_3

$result = '.\1d.svg'

$xml_con = ''
$doc_con = ''
$svg_con = ''
$path_block_con = ''
$path_lines_con = ''
$path_pegs_con = ''
$end_con = '</svg>'
$group_start = '<g>'
$group_end = '</g>'


if ($file_1_con -match '<\?xml(?=\s|>)[^>]*>')      { $xml_con          = $Matches.Values }
if ($file_1_con -match '<\!DOCTYPE(?=\s|>)[^>]*>')  { $doc_con          = $Matches.Values }
if ($file_1_con -match '<svg(?=\s|>)[^>]*>')        { $svg_con          = $Matches.Values }
if ($file_1_con -match '<path(?=\s|>)[^>]*>')       { $path_block_con   = $Matches.Values.replace('black','red').replace('lightgray','none')   }
if ($file_2_con -match '<path(?=\s|>)[^>]*>')       { $path_lines_con   = $Matches.Values.replace('black','blue').replace('lightgray','none')  }
if ($file_3_con  -match '<path(?=\s|>)[^>]*>')      { $path_pegs_con    = $Matches.Values.replace('black','green').replace('lightgray','none') }

$xml_con+$doc_con+$svg_con+$group_start+$path_block_con+$path_lines_con+$path_pegs_con+$group_end+$end_con | Out-File -FilePath $result
```

Comment: This is a `PowerShell` script, so I'm not sure if this is off-topic in this site. Maybe is allowed, since `PowerShell` can be installed both on Linux and macOS. If you just want powershell scripts than add that to your question, but if you want any kind of shell-scripting such as `bash`,`zsh`,`nu(nushell)`, etc then I think you don't have  to edit your question. Btw, see how to use `xmlstarlet` command.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this with 3 files, made with inkscape. Depending on your source, your xml-code-layout might differ, which would be a good case, to use xmlstarlet or something like that, but I'm not familiar with these tools.

However, if you have several hundrets of such files, the chances are high, that they are generated by a tool in a repeating, stable manner and therefore well suited for a tool like sed.

Assuming some files `{a,b,c}.svg`:

Cut out the paths from file 2 and 3 and store them in p23.svg:

```
sed -n '/<path/,/\/>/p' b.svg c.svg > p23.svg
```

Read in this file when encountering the `close group tag`:

```
sed -r '/^ *<\/g>$/r p23.svg' a.svg | sed 's|</g>||; s|</svg>|</g></svg>|' > abc.svg
```

The close group tag is in the wrong position, which is why the output is piped again through sed, writing to abc.svg in the end.

The paths should have unique path-ids. If you always have 3 files, to operate on, it should be easy to identify collisions and renumber the IDs or to simply renumber them without former collision check. This is left as an exercise for the reader. :)

Comment: The svg files are generated by OpenSCAD and I no control over the formatting of what it outputs so all of the files are formatted/structured exactly the same. There is no group tag in any of the files generated but for what I am using it for I what the path tags in a group.

Comment: I don't have OpenSCAD to test it out and verify, but maybe you can figure out, how to adapt the sed commands to your input format.